# SQL/BigQuery: return only the last occurence

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, partition-by

I have a table about conversations and different actions for each of them.

| conv_id | action_id | action | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | message | 10:00 |
| 1 | 12 | message | 10:05 |
| 1 | 13 | close | 10:10 |
| 2 | 21 | message | 10:00 |
| 2 | 22 | message | 10:05 |
| 2 | 23 | close | 10:10 |
| 2 | 24 | message | 10:15 |
| 3 | 31 | message | 10:00 |
| 3 | 32 | message | 10:05 |
| 3 | 33 | close | 10:10 |
| 3 | 34 | something else | 10:15 |

How can I select the last action of each conversation and keep it in a new column? I am only interested in actions “message” and “close”, the others can be ignored. So the expected outcome will look like this:

| conv_id | action_id | action | date | state |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | message | 10:00 | closed |
| 1 | 12 | message | 10:05 | closed |
| 1 | 13 | close | 10:10 | closed |
| 2 | 21 | message | 10:00 | open |
| 2 | 22 | message | 10:05 | open |
| 2 | 23 | close | 10:10 | open |
| 2 | 24 | message | 10:15 | open |
| 3 | 31 | message | 10:00 | closed |
| 3 | 32 | message | 10:05 | closed |
| 3 | 33 | close | 10:10 | closed |
| 3 | 34 | something else | 10:15 | closed |

A few details that I was struggling to include in my code:

- when conv_id is 2, if the last action is ‘message’, so the state is ‘open’, even though before that there was a ‘close’.
- when conv_id is 3, after ‘close’, there is some other action that I am not interested in, so the state takes the previous value.

here is the code to get the table:

```
-- creating a table
CREATE TABLE conversations (
  conv_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  action_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  action TEXT NOT NULL,
  date DATETIME NOT NULL
);
-- inserting some values
INSERT INTO conversations VALUES (1,11,'message','10:00');
INSERT INTO conversations VALUES (1,12,'message','10:05');
INSERT INTO conversations VALUES (1,13,'close','10:10');
INSERT INTO conversations VALUES (2,21,'message','10:00');
INSERT INTO conversations VALUES (2,22,'message','10:05');
INSERT INTO conversations VALUES (2,23,'close','10:10');
INSERT INTO conversations VALUES (2,24,'message','10:15');
INSERT INTO conversations VALUES (3,31,'message','10:00');
INSERT INTO conversations VALUES (3,32,'message','10:05');
INSERT INTO conversations VALUES (3,33,'close','10:10');
INSERT INTO conversations VALUES (3,34,'something else','10:15');
```

Thank you!

Comment: I tried to make a sample based on the real dataset, can you explain why it doesn't make sense?

Comment: I see now it is cover by the explanation. Please ignore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USING **LAST_VALUE** window function,

```sql
SELECT *, 
       CASE LAST_VALUE(IF(action IN ('message', 'close'), action, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) OVER w
         WHEN 'close' THEN 'closed'
         WHEN 'message' THEN 'open'
       END AS state  
  FROM conversations
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY conv_id ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
 ORDER BY conv_id, date;
```

Query results:

| conv_id | action_id | action | date | state |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | message | 10:00 | closed |
| 1 | 12 | message | 10:05 | closed |
| 1 | 13 | close | 10:10 | closed |
| 2 | 21 | message | 10:00 | open |
| 2 | 22 | message | 10:05 | open |
| 2 | 23 | close | 10:10 | open |
| 2 | 24 | message | 10:15 | open |
| 3 | 31 | message | 10:00 | closed |
| 3 | 32 | message | 10:05 | closed |
| 3 | 33 | close | 10:10 | closed |
| 3 | 34 | something else | 10:15 | closed |

Comment: https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ Output Style: Github Markdown

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz, I know that site above and try to use it but sometimes it requires me to take time to edit the result.  Anyway, I'll try to use it later. thanks for kind suggestion.

Comment: From BigQuery: "SAVE RESULTS" --> "Copy to clipcoard", paste and you're done.

Comment: Recommended Output Style: Github Markdown

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz, thanks. I've learned one thing from you today.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I learned so many new things from you! @Jaytiger